# Get the Time remaning Between two times

Tags: sql-server, date, between

I have two times First and Last ..I need a query that shows the time difference and if the

```
GETDATE() = now
```

then it should say In progress. Like if it is a day before then it should say '12 hours 10 Min left' and if it is happening now it should say 'In progress' and if it has passed then it should state 'Passes'

I have tries a few queries but I am not getting the desired result.

```
SELECT
    (DATEDIFF(dd, First_Half_Start, GETDATE())) -
    (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,0,First_Half_Start) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Match_Schedule;
```

Comment: You should tag the question as sql-server then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function to do is automatically. You have to build the message manually.

```
SELECT @dates=(DATEDIFF(dd, First_Half_Start, GETDATE())),
       @hours=(DATEDIFF(hour, First_Half_Start, GETDATE()))-(DATEDIFF(dd,     First_Half_Start, GETDATE()))*24,
       @minutes=(DATEDIFF(minute, First_Half_Start, GETDATE()))-(DATEDIFF(hour, First_Half_Start, GETDATE()))*60,
       @seconds=(DATEDIFF(second, First_Half_Start, GETDATE()))-(DATEDIFF(minute, First_Half_Start, GETDATE()))*60
FROM Match_Schedule;

IF ((@dates<0 or @hours<0 or @minutes<0 or @seconds<0)
 SET @status=CAST(ABS(@dates) AS VARCHAR)+' Days '+CAST(ABS(@hours) AS VARCHAR)+' hours '+CAST(ABS(@minutes) AS VARCHAR)+' minutes '+CAST(ABS(@seconds) AS VARCHAR)+' seconds left'
ELSE
 SET @status='In Progress'
```

Comment: well this is unfortunately not working ..and anyways it the first_Half_stat shouls be mapping with the GetDate() and if the date time is between the first and matchend then it should show in progress otherwise it should show the difference b/w the getdate and firstmatch..

Answer (score 0):

Looks not easy to do all on SQL Server side.

but you can calculate differences in `seconds` (because it is your accurate).

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT
    (DATEDIFF(ss, First_Half_Start, GETDATE())) AS seconds
FROM Match_Schedule;
```

Then on your client side, presents this value as you want.

something like:

**Client**

```
if (seconds > 0) {
   // create new TimeStamp object depending your language
   // make you sentence from this timestamp
} else {
  // show "in progress..."
}
```

Comment: Thank you ..But i don't have a client side..I have to do this in a stored procedure and etc..I am not good at CASE else i would have done it.

Comment: So I believe SQL Server does not provide any function to manage that.